# Error while clicking one of the exfat drives on ubuntu

Tags: exfat

When i click on my Windows system drive in the File Manager I get following error, Let me tell you that I checked all my drives with elivated cmd bu running chkdsk /x /r /f command.

Other Drives which also are exfat are being detected, i.e.  upto 150 GB drives. However this is the largest Drive around 750+ GB is not being detected & giving some page size don't match error.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/bhavik/Collections: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sda5" "/media/bhavik/Collections"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1 ' stderr: `ERROR: `pagefile.sys' real size does not equal to size (0 != 4294967296).
```

Comment: If it was last read by Windows, you must shut Windows down the nice way (click on Start ...), so that it will write all of its buffered data to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Windows system partition, boot up Windows, open the command-line wich admin-rights and execute `CHKDSK /F C:`